# Invoking javascript time "object"

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datetime, epoch

A webservice of mine returns an object in the following format.

```
{"UserID":"338040a3-6587-42bf-b22e-dc88f4ea3a9c","CompanyID":"823946a4-29d0-4546-a7ca-790648cf1e1a","FirstName":"Maxim","LastName":"Gershkovich","Username":"MaximG","Password":"62198e58d57843967bc34824be77ee2f1e2abcbbe389dc41c06810ed6f9561bf","Email":"email@email.net.au","SignupDate":"/Date(1272631625210)/","IsAdmin":true,"LoginTime":"/Date(1297129238517)/"}"
```

What is the optimal way to take the datetime value it returns and convert it to a javascript date object?

```
"SignupDate":"/Date(1272631625210)/"
```

The only way I can think of is to strip the first and last char and then do an eval. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with regex and Date constructor.

Not sure if it better, but it is safer. Eval can be evil sometimes...

So, you could do something like this:

```
var millisecs = signupDate.match(/\d+/)[0];
var date = new Date(parseInt(millisecs));
```

You could also do the regex with replace:

```
var millisecs = signupDate.replace(/[^\d]/g,""));
```